# Como usar o jquery after() em javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço em javascript a mesma função equivalente no jquery after?

Quero adicionar uma div logo após a outra, assim

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div> <!-- div 2 adicionada via javascript após a divi1 -->
```

Em jquery uso isso:

```
$('#div1').after('<div id="div2"></div>');
```

Mas queria em javascript.
Alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em JavaScript:

```
const div = document.querySelector('#div1');
div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div id="div2"></div>`);
```

Está é uma forma. Existe outras formas também. Você pode ver essa e outras formas aqui na documentação.
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: Excelente, obrigado!